# Find out which environment variables used by a command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

In a Linux environment (in my case XUbuntu), is there a way to find out which environment variables are accessed by a command which is run from the console?

It must be possible to find out about these variables, as someone has to provide the values to the program. But is there some default method to do this?

The program in question here is xprintidle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you want the variables actually used by some process running a command, you could use  [ltrace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace) and look for calls to [getenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv):

```
$ ltrace -e getenv ./your_program
```

Of course, the argument to `getenv` can be computed (so you cannot really predict it).

However, some (old or strange) applications might use the `environ` global, or the third optional argument to `main`; and some applications even change their environment using [putenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putenv), [setenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv) or `unsetenv`  (all 3 being the libc functions, not the shell builtin).

but `xprintidle` is mostly interacting with the Xorg server. I'm surprised you are expecting it to use many environment variables (except `DISPLAY`).

Comment: Something like this seems to be the way to go, but there is a problem: There are no calls to getenv, but i know for sure that an environment variable is accessed (in a library call). However, using strace i get "execve("/usr/bin/xprintidle", ["xprintidle"], [/* 41 vars */])" as first call. Does that mean, the variables are not fetched via getenv?

Comment: No -- `execve()` is always the way programs are executed (`execl()` and friends are just wrappers over it), and its third argument is a pointer array of all environment variables. You will see this call in each and every strace of an executed program.

Comment: I mentioned **ltrace** not *strace*; they are not the same!

Comment: `ltrace`'ing `getenv` may work in some cases, but beware if you're trying to trace library calls in a _language_ built on top of C.  Doing a print of environment variable `$USER` in python 2.7 and perl 5.8.5 doesn't do a `getenv`.  Try `ltrace -o log -f perl -e 'print $ENV{"USER"};' > & /dev/null && grep getenv log | egrep '\bUSER\b'` or `ltrace -o log -f python -c 'import os;print os.environ["USER"]' > & /dev/null && grep getenv log | egrep '\bUSER\b' `

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean actually accessed, or the defined environment variables for a process?

For defined environment, you can use:

`perl -pe 's,\00,\n,g' /proc/xxxx/environ`

where `xxxx` is the PID of your process.

For accessed variables, you'll have to use something like `ltrace` and check for calls to `getenv()`.

Comment: `ltrace` won't help you, since there really isn't any reason to call  `getenv()`

Comment: Eh? If you want to access the value of an environment variable, you *must* call `getenv()`!

Comment: most programs access the environment using `getenv` so `ltrace`-ing it is usually (but not always) helpful. See my answer. Some programs could get an environment variable using `environ` or the third argument to `main`. Very few programs do that in reality!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why would you call `getenv`? `setenv` sure, if you planning to `fork` and don't want to meddle with the environment array, but `getenv`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: you mean `putenv`, not `getenv`! `getenv` is quite commonly used in many programs, e.g. `ls` -see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c etc- is using it (for `QUOTING_STYLE`, `COLUMNS`, `LS_BLOCK_SIZE`, environment variables etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the environment variables that are passed to your program by using the `printenv` command.

One way that programs can look at their environment is by using the `getenv` call, so you could use a tracing program or the `LD_PRELOAD` trick to wrap that call and figure out what they are looking for.

However, not all programs use `getenv` to look at their environment.  If the program uses the following (uncommon) format for main, it can look at the environment variables through the `envp` pointer:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Also, programs can get access to the environment through the `environ` variable.

You'll probably have luck by tracing on getenv calls, but it is no guarantee---it varies from program to program.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the list of environment variables, then that is done using `env`

But determining which variables are accessed by the program is impossible, since they are all passed as they are.